# Java jar execution discrepancies between machines

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a bit of code that verifies the contents of a comma delimited file by checking each field against some regular expression - the particular regex that is causing me grief is a very basic date regex (`\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}`). If the data in that field doesn't match, it's supposed to write out to a separate file indicating that it needs to be inspected, like so:

```
private static int DATE_FIELD = 5;
File input = new File("input.txt");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){
    String[] splitLine = line.split(",");    
    Matcher m = p.matcher(splitLine[DATE_FIELD]);
    if(!m.matches) {
        // write warning to separate file
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

This code is compiled as part of a larger JAR file which is installed on 4 computers in the office (mine and three others). The jar file is invoked via a shell call made by a separate program, passing in the relevant parameters. This is part of a QC check before we import the data into our database, and the date is a required field, so if the date field was left blank, it should be flagged for review.

The regex that I used should not allow for a blank date to pass, and when I run it on my machine, it properly flags the missing dates. However, on my coworkers machines, the blank dates were somehow not flagged, as if the field wasn't checked at all, which caused a little grief when the file was being imported into the database.

In other words, there is some discrepancy between our machines that caused the code to execute incorrectly on their machines, but not mine. All of the machines have Java 8 (not sure exactly which version, but they should all be the same version). How can that be?

Comment: My guess is that you don't read the file you think you're reading, or that you don't write warnings correctly, or that you're not writing them to the file you think. Add logging statements, showing the absolute paths of the files, the values of the lines being checked, etc.

Comment: It would help if you included the code for the `splitLine` method.  Also, some sample input would be useful.  Also, are all of your co-workers using the same OS that you use?  That matters more than the Java version, since `FileReader` uses the system’s default charset.

Comment: @VGR `splitLine` is the result of `java.String.split()`. However I think GKR has helped me nail down the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to specify the encoding of the file(s) you want to read. 
  [The constructors of `FileReader`] generally use the platform default encoding. So determine the actual encoding and use something like `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input), <encoding>)`
- Check the java version for each machine. Verify that the designated java is actually called
- Check the encoding of the file(s) itself (UTF-8, CP1252, or ...)

Comment: So it would appear that the file in question, when opened in TextWrangler, shows its encoding as "Western (ASCII)" instead of the usual UTF-8, which is likely the source of my problem. However there are several steps in the processing before this code executes, and the original file started as UTF-8... so it seems the root cause lies elsewhere. I feel this is probably the correct answer; I'll try explicitly defining the encoding and come back to accept this after some time has passed and I'm confident the issue is resolved.

Comment: I tried as I said above, but it still hasn't solved the problem and requires further investigation; however I accepted this answer as I said I would, since this is still probably helpful.